# How to run a url from inside a python script to command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, command-line, uwp-maps

I have this command line text that I want to run inside my python script to the command line. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
explorer "ms-drive-to:? 



destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake"
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: No it don't I tried that but it just opens my file explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to effectively run this in python shell,like this: # it will open windows map

```
>>> !explorer "ms-drive-to:? 
destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake"
```

If you want to run in code, do like others method.All the answers are correct.

```
import os

command_str = 'explorer "ms-drive-to:? destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake"'
os.system(command_str)
# it will open windows map, and driving directions to Green Lake from your current location.
```

Be careful to use double quotes, single quotes will not be recognized correctly!
[image: results]

windows uwp info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do something like is described in this post:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17017/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-command-in-a-python-script

Seems like you should use `subprocess`:

[Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/4256153#4256153)

Comment: I tried that but it just open ups my file explorer. Like if you try running this: explorer "ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake"    from command line it goes to the maps in windows.

Comment: What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Glad to hear. Can you please mark it as best answer?